# How to exactly search current word?

Tags: search, functions

Want to exactly matching current word with below function.

```
function! My_Exact_Search ()
   let CurrentWord = expand("<cword>")
   exec "/\<".CurrentWord."\>"
endfunction
```

But get error: `E486: Pattern not found: <word>`.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` command does this natively.

The problem with your function is you need to escape your `/` or use literal-string (I recommend).

```
let @/ = '/\<'.CurrentWord.'\>'
```

You also should be using `:normal` to create the search.

```
execute "normal! /\\<".expand('<cword>')."\\>\<cr>"
```

For more help see:

```
:h *
:h literal-string
:h quote/
```

Comment: Yes, `*` is working. Tried `exec '/\<'.CurrentWord.'\>'`, but nothing happened.

Comment: I just tried `:execute '/\<'.expand('<cword>').'\>` and it works for me

Comment: Yes, directly run the command is working, but if run from function then nothing is happening.